# Kubernetes: enable host network for all pods/services

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubelet

Is it possible to enable host network between host and cluster for all installed pods (or services) by default without modifying yaml files? Modifying only kubelet or docker setup

On pod it's possible with flag

```
hostNetwork: true
```

Comment: What do you mean by enabling host network for services and pods ?

Comment: When I have installed deployment on cluster by default I can access it on host using port forwarding from k8s service like 8080:30546TCP. And I can use port 30546 on localhost for connection. But adding option "hostNetwork: true" I'm able to connect with port 8080. And my goal is to enable such forwarding by default for all deployments (or just on services)

Comment: You want to completely disable the Kubernetes networking layer, inter-service DNS, intra-cluster load balancing from services, _etc._?  Why?

Comment: U should elaborate more on ur question... Service is used as way to expose a set of pods as network service.. if u dont use service which u managed to do via port forward  it allows you to access the internal pod from your localhost via proxy (pod refers to itself as localhost in that sense).As for using hostnework: true, pod is now accessible  on all network interfaces of the host machine , downside of this : apps with same ports CANT run at the same time...."ur goal is to enable forwarding by default" meaning thats u want to  expose your pod thats the purpose of service

Comment: I want to have shared network between host and cluster to have static access to each pod without port forwarding rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got your question . You basically want all port forwarding from host port to the pod port.

To do :
1.- Add these to your port config in manifest

```
name: portA

containerPort: 9100

hostPort: 9100
```

Add this to your deployment manifest . Now the pod will be accessible by directly using nodeIp:9100 which will enable the pod to run in the hostport 9100.